# Primefaces: DataTable outside border

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

I have a  PrimeFaces dataTable inside of a panel. But it has a disturbing outside border i've wanted to delete it but failed. Here are xhtml codes:

```
 <p:panel styleClass="centerPanel" id="centerPanel">
       <p:dataTable styleClass="DataTable" style="width:100%;" liveScroll="true" value="#{PanelController.panelList}" var="GridPanel" scrollable="true" scrollRows="20" scrollHeight="470" rows="5">
               <p:column>

               </p:column>
       </p:dataTable>
   </p:panel>
```

And here are the css codes:

```
.ui-datatable.DataTable th, .ui-datatable.DataTable tr, .ui-datatable.DataTable td, .ui-datatable.DataTable {
background: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.50) none;
border: none; !important;
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); !important;
-webkit-background-clip:border;!important;
color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.DataTable.ui-datatable table thead {
    display: none;
    border: none; !important;
}
```

and it seems [image: like]

Comment: Do you want to remove all the border inside your table (including border for filter boxes) or just the wrapping borders?

Comment: i just want to remove all borders including wrapper borders. And i realized sth more weird transparent background colors are disabled for dataTable rows i think i have to use background images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following css style:

```
    .DataTable table > thead > tr > th,
    .DataTable table > tbody,
    .DataTable table > tbody > tr,
    .DataTable table > tbody > tr > td {
        border: none !important;
    }
```

of in case if your don't care about your filter input boxes and such elements just do

```
   .DataTable table * {
       border: none !important;
   }
```

Comment: thanks a lot! what u think about row transparency? I have a background image for my page but dataTable background color property just doesn't work for transparency. (color like rgba(220,220,220,0.50)

Comment: sorry for leaving that temporary id before the selectors, since your dataTable have the `DataTable` styleClass the correct selector is `.DataTable`.